# Best day ticket for 3 days in Amsterdam, sleeping close to Halweg-Zwanenburg

Tags: public-transport, tickets, amsterdam

It seems that there are no day tickets including gvb and a single NS train travel to Amsterdam Centraal (excluding schipol).

So till now my research says: "The Amsterdam Travel Ticket" for 3 days at 25 euro + paper ticket Halweg-Zwanenbug <-> Amsterdam.

Am I correct? Are there any NS day tickets for these two stations?

(anonymous OV card is out of question, until the minimum 20 euro charge is required)

EDIT: thanks for the replies. I realized that I was looking for transport zones, like the a-b-c in Berlin. Amsterdam doesn't have it, and the only option is what @JaneDoe1337 says: gvb for 21 euro/96 hours plus return tickets for the NS trips. My gf correctly says that going downtown 2 times per day in two means almost 32 euro per day. With this knowledge it's probably less expensive to rent a house inside the gvb zone.
Anyway, we cross the fingers for good weather and bike rental :)

Comment: You can get the charge for an anonymous OV card back when you leave at the NS desk, but it costs 1 euro (plus 7.50 you pay for the card in the first place). Three "paper tickets" (single use smart cards) cost 3 euro extra. Are you sure the 25 euro for the travel ticket is going to be worth it?

Comment: How often do you plan to travel between these stations? The stations are VERY close to each other so travelling wouldn't be very expensive and you might be better off buying return tickets and getting gvb day passes.

Comment: When I was traveling heavily between Amsterdam and Rotterdam, blablacar rides were available for 1/3 of trains price. Probably worth checking.

Answer (score 3):

If you are happy to use the bus, there is an Amsterdam and surrounding areas pass.
You can use [the general public transport planner](http://9292.nl/en) to see which buses are available.
Station to station, the travel time to Amsterdam Centraal will be longer, but if you want to be somewhere else in the city, you will find the differences decrease fast.

[The pass is a day pass](http://www.amsterdamtips.com/tips/transport-tickets.php) and might cover more than you need:

> 7. Amsterdam & Region Day Card - This disposable OV-chip ticket costs €13.50 and gives you unlimited travel on buses, trams and metro for 24 hours in Amsterdam and the surrounding region. It is valid day and night on any GVB transport plus regional bus services from Connexxion (incuding the 197 airport bus) and EBS - so could be used to visit the Waterland region, Haarlem and Zaanse Schans by bus. Note, it is not valid for NS train travel. Card is validated on first check-in, you must check-in and -out for each trip

If you are happy enough with buses and do not need them in the city, you could just use an OV Chip card and make sure there is no less than €4.50 on it.
Or you can combine a single ride into the city with a day or multiple day pass.
Your ticket price where your pass will start will be lower than the ticket price to the center of the city and you might need to ask the driver to help you check out and in a the right spot.

Which pass is the best for you depends on how much you want travel when within Amsterdam as well on how many touristy attractions covered by some of the passes you want to do.
I think that if your travel needs are low, just the OV chip card with the bus money on it might be the best choice.

To the right of this page you can see a list of related Q, many of those will hold helpful advice for tickets against passes for Amsterdam.